# MKMapView Coordinates Are Showing 0

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, mapkit

I have an MKMapKit and am trying to get the center coordinate out of it based on where the user is looking.

I am using the following code to get the coordinates out:

```
float lat = self.mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude;
float lon = self.mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude;
float latDelta = self.mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta;
float lonDelta = self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta;
```

It works fine in the simulator, but reports 0 for everything on the device.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is this code?  When it "reports 0", is `self.mapView` set to `nil`?  How is the reporting done exactly (NSLog, UILabel, other)?  Is the device the same hardware type and iOS version as the simulator?

Comment: @brandontreb you should use CLLocationDegrees (aka double) for lat/lng etc

Comment: Why use both centerCoordinate and region? Try self.mapView.region.center.latitude and self.mapView.region.center.longitude. And definitely check for a nil mapView and store the coordinates and lengths in doubles/CLLocationDegrees, as Anna and aprato said.

Answer (score 0):

It's shows correct, the Coordinate region values are shown below

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoord;
    topLeftCoord.latitude = -90;
    topLeftCoord.longitude = 180;

  CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoord;
    bottomRightCoord.latitude = 90;
    bottomRightCoord.longitude = -180;
```

use mapview current location values for lan & lat

```
float lat = self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude;
float lon = self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude;
float latDelta = self.mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta;
float lonDelta = self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the mapView outlet was nil.  Which is odd as it's hooked up correctly.  Once I set it to a strong reference, everything was fine.  Maybe some silly iOS7 bug.

Thanks for all of the feedback guys!